# Python: Finding key with its value having the maximum absolute value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So say I have a dictionary like:

```
d = {'A': 2 , 'B': -4, 'C': 3}
```

I want to return 'B'. In the past my dictionary didn't have to store negative values and I had just been checking for the key with the maximum value with:

```
maxkey = max(d, key=lambda y: d[y])
```

So I thought I could try something like:

```
maxkey = max(d, key=lambda abs(y): d[y])
```

or

```
maxkey = max(d, key=lambda y: d[abs(y)])
```

but both return error messages. Also, I need to be able to do this more than once, so I can't get away with replacing all the values in the entire dictionary with their absolute values...

Answer (score 6):

I think you want:

```
maxkey = max(d, key=lambda y: abs(d[y]))
```

Comment: Right that is what I was looking for, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem...Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

When using a `lambda` expression in Python, you want to have the right side of the colon to be the function you're performing. If before, you wanted to sort by the values, ie. `d[y]` and now you want to take the absolute value of those, you just do it like so:

```
maxkey = max(d, key=lambda y: abs(d[y]))
```